# Time-Independent Perturbation: Correction Components are Orthogonal to the Original State (Townsend)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory, approximations

I am reading Townsend's A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics, Second Edition. While developing the first order correction to the eigenstate (in time independent, non-degenerate Perturbation theory), the book does the steps below (pg 384-385).

[image]

[image]

Here $\psi_n$ represents the $n^{th}$ perturbed eigenstate and $\phi_n$ represents the $n^{th}$ un-perturbed eigenstate. The superscripts represent the order of correction. Here is what I don't understand:

1. How did we introduce the $e^{ia\lambda}$ term in 11.21? I don't follow the explanation cited, especially due to the repetition of the second order terms.
2. What does it mean that its "phase can be chosen arbitrarily"? If I multiply the left side of 11.21 with $e^{ib}$, I would have to do the same on the right. Granted I can select $b$ such that the first term on the right has a net phase of zero, but what about the other terms on the right?

Questions about this orthogonality have been considered [elsewhere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434251/time-independent-perturbation-theory-why-ith-order-perturbations-are-orthogo), however, I did not see these particular issues discussed.

Comment: Use MathJax, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two steps in Eq. (11.21) are just using the fact that
$$
1 + i a \lambda + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2) = e^{i a \lambda} + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2).
$$
Of course, the two $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$ terms on each side would be different if we actually expanded the power series out to that order;  but since we're not working to that order, we can just treat "$\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$" like a wastebasket where we dump the terms that "don't matter" at this order.

You can use a similar logic to see what's happening with the phase.  If we multiply both sides by $e^{-ia \lambda}$, as you are effectively suggesting, then the last two terms in (11.21) would become
$$
e^{-i a \lambda} \lambda \sum \text{[summands]} + e^{-i a \lambda} \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2) = (1 -i a \lambda) \lambda \sum \text{[summands]} + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2) \\= \lambda \sum \text{[summands]} + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)
$$
where again we have just thrown all of the $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$ terms that arise into the big scrap heap at the end of the equation.